# How to use excel function COUNTIF in R?

Tags: r

For example, I have this data frame:

```
id  name    date
1   susan   1/1/2020
2   jhon    1/1/2020
3   susan   1/1/2020
4   eric    2/4/2020
5   eric    2/4/2020
6   susan   2/1/2020
7   eric    2/4/2020
```

And I need this:

```
id  name    date    output
1   susan   1/1/2020    1
2   jhon    1/8/2020    1
3   susan   1/1/2020    2
4   eric    2/4/2020    1
5   eric    2/4/2020    2
6   susan   2/9/2019    1
7   eric    2/4/2020    3
```

The output column is possible in excel with COUNTIF function, but I need this using R.

I group by name and date.

Comment: Could you please set out the criteria your countif is operating on and could you also please include your data in dataframe format so that we can help you.

Comment: hello - can you double check your desired output? I can't follow how you went from input to output

Comment: I'm not sure you would get this result using excel countif function. What it seems as if you are asking for is to add a cumulative sum on grouped names and dates. I think the distinction is between the use of the words 'count' and 'cumulative sum'. Is that a fair assessment of the question?  Check out the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification.

Does this give you what you want?

```
# data

tib <- tibble( name = c("susan", "jhon", "susan", "eric", "eric", "susan", "eric"), 
              date = c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "2/4/2020", "2/4/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/4/2020"))
```

```
# datawrangle

tib1 <-
  tib %>% 
  group_by(name, date) %>% 
  mutate(output = row_number())
```

Which results in:

```
tib1
## # A tibble: 7 x 3
## # Groups:   name, date [4]
##   name  date     output
##   <chr> <chr>     <int>
## 1 susan 1/1/2020      1
## 2 jhon  1/1/2020      1
## 3 susan 1/1/2020      2
## 4 eric  2/4/2020      1
## 5 eric  2/4/2020      2
## 6 susan 2/1/2020      1
## 7 eric  2/4/2020      3
```

Comment: You get a similar output by using `tib %>% group_by(name, date) %>% tally()`

Comment: @Martin Gal indeed you do, the description of the tally function in dplyr refers to the group_by() %>% summarise(count = n()) process.

Comment: thanks but i need the result i put in the original post. 

I don't want to count the ones that are repeated, what I need is to list them

Comment: Just a small alternative to Peter's answer, again with tally: `tib %>% group_by(name,date) %>% add_tally(name="output")`

Comment: @ Martin Gal To be honest I think using add_tally is the better option as this is doing what the OP wants directly instead of  counting by the row_number() proxy. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

with(dataframe, ave(seq_along(name), name, date, FUN=seq_along))

from this post:  [R enumerate duplicates in a dataframe with unique value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393814/r-enumerate-duplicates-in-a-dataframe-with-unique-value)

thanks for the other answers.